# Website able to identify the IP address on an https connection?

Tags: https, isp

When I connect to a site via https, can the website host provider determine or verify my IP address?

If so, in what process is my IP address exposed to the provider?

Thank you.

Comment: Everything noted by Tetsujin is correct, but you can make an effort to hide that information by using a VPN service (nordvpn, purevpn, etc). When you use a VPN, you make a secure connection to the VPN server which has its own IP. Your request goes encrypted to it (so nothing in between sees the contents, including your ISP and ISP only knows you're talking to the VPN, nothing beyond it) and then is exposed from the VPN on, so the HTTP server only sees the VPN server's IP address, nothing on the other side of it (so it has no idea who/where you are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any connection you ever make exposes your IP Address to the other end - that's how they know who to send the data back to.
HTTPS only means that the data is encrypted between those two points.

Take a simple analogy...
You send a cheque in the mail to buy something.
The envelope is your 'encryption', no-one can see inside it.
At the other end they take your cheque & cash it.
Who do they send the goods to?
You have to have enclosed your return address to get the package back.
In a networking scenario, this is done by writing your address on the back of the envelope.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Not the destination where the https packet is decrypted,
at ISP, can thay analyze my https packet and find out my IP address?

Comment: Your IP Address is never a secret. Taking the above analogy, though no-one can see what's inside the envelope, the return address is written on the outside.

Comment: @uuy553: They don't _have_ to analyze HTTPS because IP addresses don't live inside HTTPS – it's the other way around. Think of IP packet as the box/envelope, and HTTPS as the box's contents. Doesn't matter what you put inside – you still have to write the sender/recipient on the outside. So anything you transfer over the Internet, no matter how encrypted, will have the sender's and recipient's IP addresses "written on the outside".

Comment: One last thing - while HTTPS will conceal most of the connection information, any current request will expose the domain name (such as example.com) in the request header. This means that both the IP and the website you're visiting will likely be exposed to anyone at the ISP, router, or malicious users on the network that might be sniffing your traffic.